# Metro Theme system brushes don't change

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on my first Metro application and I'm wanting to change my theme from the default dark theme to a light theme.  It appears Metro has some built in themes if you look at the platform pane in VS11 and Blend.  I assumed changing the Theme from Default(which is dark) to Light would change the system brushes from dark to light.  It does appear to work in the designer but when running the program everything is still dark.

Am I doing something wrong to get the System brushes to change, or am I missing the point of what Platform theme is?  Or is it just a bug?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the html page you want to change and then locate `<!-- WinJS references -->`at the head of the document, and then change the stylesheet reference from `ui-dark.css`to `ui-light.css`.

Do this for all html pages in the app including the `default.html` page.

Comment: I think it's a bug, the Platform options don't seem to affect the actual app. Everything works well though in HTML.

Comment: @Michael @keithwarren7 Yay! at last found the solution. To change the theme, simply open `app.xaml` and at the very top on the second line where it says `x:Class`, include `RequestedTheme="Light"` after the app name, so now everything should look like this: `x:Class="Application3.App" RequestedTheme="Light"`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks!  For whatever reason Microsoft thinks it's a good idea to have a different look for design time and run time.  So to get Light theme at design time you have to set Platform to light and at run time you have to set RequestedTheme="Light".  I sure hope by RTM Microsoft doesn't have a different theme for run time and design time.

Comment: Yep, RequestedTheme="Light" was the fix for me. Was so annoying, tried every option in that Theme drop down in the Platform tab and nothing was changing on my built app. Quite alarming that bug made it through to launch, but let's hope MS gets on top of it by RTM.

Comment: Ok well as John Bowen pointed out, apparently the Platform tab is only for making changes to your Simulator, a bit disconcerting. Let's hope this is mentioned in a note on the tab or something then.

Comment: Yup. Changing it in just `default.html` doesn't work. "..Do this for all html pages..". +10!

Answer (score 0):

The Platform pane isn't for making changes to your application itself. It's for setting up the simulation environment that you want to use as your design-time context. Changing the Display setting, for example, doesn't reset your screen resolution or resize your app - it still runs full screen. Similarly, Theme is an OS setting which you won't see changes in at runtime unless you change the OS theme in the control panel. This is similar in concept to how WPF uses different themes with different control templates for Aero, Royale(XP style), and Classic(Win2K style) depending on what the user is running.

Comment: So if I want to have a lighter theme I will completely ignore the system brushes and create my own?

Comment: Basically. Also be aware that by doing so you're ignoring the user's preferences, which is fine if you're going for a very specific look.

Comment: John, none of the Metro Applications I've downloaded from the Windows Store use the dark theme.  So it seems most Metro Applications are ignoring the user's preferences.  Which is why I thought you were able to override the default look.